# NullPointerException when a Firebase Authentication activity is setting a setOnClickListener

Tags: android, firebase

I tried to implement login activity with Firebase Auth into my main project, as a stand-alone login activity the Authentication works as I tested it on a new project. But when I try to implement it in my Main Project, it gives a null pointer exception.

The error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.test.testbv.Login.onCreate(Login.java:47)
```

Here is the MainActivity.Java, where it checks if the user is authorized on the onCreate otherwise it takes the user to the Login activity.

```
package com.test.testbv;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference mRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) {
            // User is signed in.
        } else {
            // No user is signed in.
            redirectToLogin();
        }

        // Action Bar

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("Coupons List");

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // Set Layout
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        // Send Query to Firebase Db
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Data");

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    public void redirectToLogin () {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        // getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        // return true;

        // Inflates the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it's present

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

        // Filter
//        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        MenuItem itemFilter = menu.findItem(R.id.filterMenu);


        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                firebaseSearch(query);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                // Filters down as you type

                firebaseSearch(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    // Filter Data
    private void firebaseFilter(String searchText) {
        String query = searchText.toLowerCase();

        Query firebaseFilterQuery = mRef.orderByChild("category").startAt(query).endAt(query + "\uf8ff");

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ViewHolder>(
                        Model.class,
                        R.layout.row,
                        ViewHolder.class,
                        firebaseFilterQuery
                ) {
                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Model model, int position) {
                        viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getTitle(), model.getDescription(), model.getImage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                        ViewHolder viewHolder = super.onCreateViewHolder(parent, viewType);

                        viewHolder.setOnClickListener(new ViewHolder.clickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {


                                // get Data from firebase at the position clicked
                                String mTitle = getItem(position).getTitle();
                                String mDesc = getItem(position).getDescription();
                                String mImage = getItem(position).getImage();


                                // Pass this data to new activity
                                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), PostDetailActivity.class);

                                intent.putExtra("image", mImage);
                                intent.putExtra("title", mTitle);
                                intent.putExtra("description", mDesc);
                                startActivity(intent);

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {

                            }

                        });

                        return viewHolder;
                    }
                };
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    }



    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ViewHolder>(
                        Model.class,
                        R.layout.row,
                        ViewHolder.class,
                        mRef
                ) {
                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Model model, int position) {
                        viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getTitle(), model.getDescription(), model.getImage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                        ViewHolder viewHolder = super.onCreateViewHolder(parent, viewType);

                        viewHolder.setOnClickListener(new ViewHolder.clickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                                // get Data from firebase at the position clicked
                                String mTitle = getItem(position).getTitle();
                                String mDesc = getItem(position).getDescription();
                                String mImage = getItem(position).getImage();

                                // Pass this data to new activity
                                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), PostDetailActivity.class);

                                intent.putExtra("image", mImage);
                                intent.putExtra("title", mTitle);
                                intent.putExtra("description", mDesc);
                                startActivity(intent);

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {

                            }

                        });

                        return viewHolder;
                    }
                };
        // Set adapter to recycler view
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }
}
```

The Login Activity with the .xml below:

```
package com.test.testbv;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "EmailPassword";

    private TextView mStatusTextView;
    private TextView mDetailTextView;
    private EditText mEmailField;
    private EditText mPasswordField;

    // [START declare_auth]
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    // [END declare_auth]


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Views
        mStatusTextView = findViewById(R.id.status);
        mDetailTextView = findViewById(R.id.detail);
        mEmailField = findViewById(R.id.fieldEmail);
        mPasswordField = findViewById(R.id.fieldPassword);

        // Buttons
        findViewById(R.id.emailSignInButton).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.emailCreateAccountButton).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.signOutButton).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.verifyEmailButton).setOnClickListener(this);

        // [START initialize_auth]
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        // [END initialize_auth]
    }

    // [START on_start_check_user]
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        updateUI(currentUser);
    }
    // [END on_start_check_user]

    private void createAccount(String email, String password) {
        Log.d(TAG, "createAccount:" + email);
        if (!validateForm()) {
            return;
        }

//        showProgressDialog();

        // [START create_user_with_email]
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            updateUI(null);
                        }

                        // [START_EXCLUDE]
//                        hideProgressDialog();
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                });
        // [END create_user_with_email]
    }

    private void signIn(String email, String password) {
        Log.d(TAG, "signIn:" + email);
        if (!validateForm()) {
            return;
        }

//        showProgressDialog();

        // [START sign_in_with_email]
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            updateUI(user);
                            redirectToMain();

                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            updateUI(null);
                        }

                        // [START_EXCLUDE]
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            mStatusTextView.setText(R.string.auth_failed);
                        }
//                        hideProgressDialog();
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                });
        // [END sign_in_with_email]
    }

    private void signOut() {
        mAuth.signOut();
        updateUI(null);
    }

    public void redirectToMain() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void sendEmailVerification() {
        // Disable button
        findViewById(R.id.verifyEmailButton).setEnabled(false);

        // Send verification email
        // [START send_email_verification]
        final FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        user.sendEmailVerification()
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        // [START_EXCLUDE]
                        // Re-enable button
                        findViewById(R.id.verifyEmailButton).setEnabled(true);

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this,
                                    "Verification email sent to " + user.getEmail(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Log.e(TAG, "sendEmailVerification", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this,
                                    "Failed to send verification email.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                });
        // [END send_email_verification]
    }

    private boolean validateForm() {
        boolean valid = true;

        String email = mEmailField.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            mEmailField.setError("Required.");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            mEmailField.setError(null);
        }

        String password = mPasswordField.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            mPasswordField.setError("Required.");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            mPasswordField.setError(null);
        }

        return valid;
    }

    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
//        hideProgressDialog();
        if (user != null) {
            mStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.emailpassword_status_fmt,
                    user.getEmail(), user.isEmailVerified()));
            mDetailTextView.setText(getString(R.string.firebase_status_fmt, user.getUid()));

            findViewById(R.id.emailPasswordButtons).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.emailPasswordFields).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.signedInButtons).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            findViewById(R.id.verifyEmailButton).setEnabled(!user.isEmailVerified());
        } else {
            mStatusTextView.setText(R.string.signed_out);
            mDetailTextView.setText(null);

            findViewById(R.id.emailPasswordButtons).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.emailPasswordFields).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.signedInButtons).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int i = v.getId();
        if (i == R.id.emailCreateAccountButton) {
            createAccount(mEmailField.getText().toString(), mPasswordField.getText().toString());
        } else if (i == R.id.emailSignInButton) {
            signIn(mEmailField.getText().toString(), mPasswordField.getText().toString());
        } else if (i == R.id.signOutButton) {
            signOut();
        } else if (i == R.id.verifyEmailButton) {
            sendEmailVerification();
        }
    }
}
```

The XML below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/emailpassword_title_text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/signed_out" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="Firebase User ID: 123456789abc" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/emailPasswordFields"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/fieldEmail"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="@string/hint_email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/fieldPassword"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="@string/hint_password"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/emailPasswordButtons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/emailPasswordFields"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/emailSignInButton"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/sign_in" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/emailCreateAccountButton"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/create_account" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/signedInButtons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:weightSum="2.0">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/signOutButton"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:text="@string/sign_out"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/verifyEmailButton"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:text="@string/verify_email"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.testbv">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".PostDetailActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".FAQ" />
        <activity android:name=".Login" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` I think you set wrong layout to your `Login` activity.

Comment: Yes. I missed that, didn't read through it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `activity_main` layout in login screen.

Comment: Thank you, made this mistake when I possibly shifted the project.